# Error in x[[method]](...) : attempt to apply non-function in testthat test when sourcing file

Tags: r, testthat

I am developing an R app and came up with a workaround to integrate [testthat](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat) in it (it usually requires your project to be a package) by adding a `DESCRIPTION` file to the project root.

I got this method from a colleague who managed to get it to work like this.

The problem is, when I try to test anything (even empty test files), I get this error:

```
Error in x[[method]](...) : attempt to apply non-function
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> o_apply -> lapply -> FUN -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

What I know is that this appears **only** on macOS. My colleague can still run this app without problems on Windows.

What's the deal with it?

The [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for reproducing this error would be:

- create a minimum `DESCRIPTION` file with content:

  ```
  Package: testpckg
  ```
- add testthat to your project:

  ```
  usethis::use_testthat()
  usethis::use_test("foo")
  ```
- create empty file `bar.R`
- in `test-foo.R`, source bar: `source("bar.R")`

RStudio Version 1.1.447,
R version 3.4.4, Mac OS X 10_13_4

Comment: Could you post the code you are running that throws the error?

Comment: I am using quite a lot of files, so it was easier to reproduce the error in a new, clean project. I edited the description.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my macbook unfortunately.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve your problem? (A colleague runs the same code without this problem!)

Comment: See my edit to the answer below...

Comment: I use version:`2.0.1` is working fine with `usethis::use_testthat()`
and `usethis::use_test("foo")` but `context("test-foo")` instead of `source("bar.R")`
`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This appears to be due to a bug in `testthat 2.0.0`. Adding a `context("Name of test context")` to the [top of each test file](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/700#issuecomment-367675035) worked for me (tested using Ubuntu and Windows).